# Is there an easier way to do multiple nested IFs in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure in mysql that has 10 'in' parameters.

The problem is that some parameters might be null or have a value. In case of null it shouldn't try to look for that column in the `where` part. Then there is the same for column sorting.

The way I have it currently looks like this:

```
if(par1 is null) then
  if(par2 is null) then
    if(par3 is null) then
      -- some query: select * from blabla where 1=1 order by something
    else
      -- other query: select * from blabla where col3=par3 order by something
  else
    if(par3 is null) then
      -- some query: select * from blabla where col2=par2 order by something
    else
      -- other query: select * from blabla where col2=par2 and col3=par3 order by something
else
  -- same as in the 'if' part
```

So as you can see, it gets tedious to work with very quickly, now imagine this being done for many parameters.
How can I simplify this, if possible? Any advice?

Comment: This can be quite complicated if you want the individual queries to make use of indexes for optimization.

Comment: This kind of problem *can* be symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 0):

You could write a single query that takes all the parameter at once and uses `coalesce()` to ignore `null` values:

```
select * 
from blabla 
where 
        col1 = coalesce(@par1, col1)
    and col2 = coalesce(@par2, col2)
    and col3 = coalesce(@par3, col3)
order by something
```

You also spell this as the longer, but maybe clearer:

```
select * 
from blabla 
where 
        (@par1 is null or col1 = @par1)
    and (@par2 is null or col2 = @par2)
    and (@par3 is null or col3 = @par3)
order by something
```

Comment: How do i apply the same logic in `order by`?

Comment: @king: I don't know what you are exactly saying. Your original question had no mention of sorting logic (which is not the same concept as *filtering* logic). Probably, you should ask a new question for this (I would suggest providing sample data and expected results to make your problem statement clearer).